# Searching excel files for string in file through multiple folder directories not working

Tags: python

I have this code where I am trying to search a Directory and Sub Directories for a specified string within .xls and .xlsx files and return the file name for now. When I run this - I get a return of each file directory path as text for the files ending in .xls and .xlsx and the search string parameter I use under those same returned results. The code is not isolating the files with the string - rather, just returning the file path as text for all results and adding my string parameter to search for under that. What could be happening here? and is it possible to pass a list here and copy the discovered files to a folder? That is where I am trying to get with this in the end. Thank you.

```
import os
import openpyxl

def findFiles(strings, dir, subDirs, fileContent, fileExtensions):
    filesInDir = []
    foundFiles = []
    filesFound = 0

    if not subDirs:
        for filename in os.listdir(dir):
            if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dir, filename).replace("\\", "/")):
                filesInDir.append(os.path.join(dir, filename).replace("\\", "/"))
    else:
        for root, subdirs, files in os.walk(dir):
            for f in files:
                if not os.path.isdir(os.path.join(root, f).replace("\\", "/")):
                    filesInDir.append(os.path.join(root, f).replace("\\", "/"))
    print(filesInDir)
    
    if filesInDir:
        for file in filesInDir:
            print("Current file: "+file)
            
            filename, extension = os.path.splitext(file)
            if fileExtensions:
                fileText = extension
            else:
                fileText = os.path.basename(filename).lower()
                if fileContent:
                    fileText +=  getFileContent(file).lower()
            
            for string in strings:
                print(string)
                if string in fileText:
                    foundFiles.append(file)
                    filesFound += 1
                    break
    return foundFiles

def getFileContent(filename):
    
    if filename.partition(".")[2] in supportedTypes:
        if filename.endswith(".xls"):
            content = ""
            with openpyxl.load_workbook(filename) as pdf:
                for x in range(0, len(pdf.pages)):
                    page = pdf.pages[x]
                    content = content + page.extract_text()
            return content
        elif filename.endswith(".xlsx"):
            with openpyxl.load_workbook(filename, 'r') as f:
                content = ""
                lines = f.readlines()
                for x in lines:
                    content = content + x
            f.close()
            return content
    else:
        return ""

supportedTypes = [".xls", ".xlsx"]
print(findFiles(strings=["55413354"], dir="C:/Users/User/",  subDirs=True, fileContent=True, fileExtensions=False))
```

Expected output sample - reflects a find for string '55413354` - as in, that string was located in below file name only out of 3 files.

```
Excel File Name 123
```

Actual output - Returns everything - no filter is happening, and includes my search string under the file name.

```
path/Excel File Name 123
55413354

path/Excel File Name 321
55413354

path/Excel File Name 111
55413354
```

Comment: What is the expected output and the actual output?  Might it have something to do with the ```print(string)```?

Comment: Sorry - I edited. Expected output for now is to return the names of the files that contain the searched string that I assign. Later, I'd like to call a list into that search parameter and take any files that contain items from the list and copy them to a destination folder.

Actual output is just returning all file names in the form of path+filename, and then also returning my search string that I assign under each one of those. So no filtering for the search string is happening and for some reason I get a return of the search string. I'm just getting all results that end in .xls/.xlsx

Comment: Please include a sample of the expected output and the actual output in your post.

Comment: Updated @ewong - Thank you for helping me be more specific.

Comment: You have a ```print(string)``` within your ```findfiles()``` function.   Might that be the reason why you're getting the search string printed out?

Comment: I have no idea man @ewong - Tried removing that piece and same output occurs. I'm just trying to filter a string of text and return the file names that contain it to start with - If I can get that to work I can work at modifying the code later to copy and move to a location the files where the string is present. The code starts getting crazy complex for my skill set.

Comment: Removed the print string and it still does it.